# C++ Xcode iOS project errors

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

I'm working on a iOS project which as several c++ class. But as it seems compiling them are not straightforwards. I tired different methods but all the time give some errors.

1) First I renamed .m;class to .mm and try to compile and it gives a error. in this line

```
SInt16 *editBuffer = audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDat;
```

`Error - "Cannot initialize a variable of type 'SInt16 *' (aka 'short *') with an lvalue of type 'void *'"`

2) When setting Other Linker Flags to -ObjC++ it gives these two errors. 
Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?

```
'deque' file not found - for #include<deque>
```

Anyone has any idea , what's wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linker flags will not effect the compiler. Have you tried setting the compiler option for Objective-C++?

Comment: Yes, it gives the error number 1.

Comment: First error is due to a noncompliant type. If my assumption about this involving CoreAudio is right, audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDat is the buffer address. SInt16* and void* types pointing to the same buffer won't behave the same where pointer math is concerned. You need to either cast the void* to SInt16*, or retype editBuffer to a compliant type such as void* or char*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is expected. C++ is finicky about void pointers.

```
SInt16 *editBuffer = (SInt16 *)(audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDat);
```

or

```
SInt16 *editBuffer = static_cast<SInt16 *>(audioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mDat);
```

See [Casting To and From void*](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14446).